# calling derived class method using base class object

Tags: java

I have 6 classes as shown in figure below.
Now, `class A` has an object of class `B` as a private variable defined. Also class `A` methods calls many methods from class B, for example `B.method1()`.
Now, class `A_Base1` is which is derived from class `A`, needs to call methods from the derived class `B_Base1`; for example `B1.method2()`. And also methods of class `A_Base2` needs to call methods from class `B_Base2`; for example `B2.method3()`.

Now in class A I define the variable as -

`private B bObject`

Now in method of `A_Base1`, I cannot cannot call the methods like `bObject.method2()` since its a base class object.

I need suggestions on -

Is it possible to call derived class object methods using base class object?
Or do I need to re-design this scenario in some other good way?

[image: figure]

Comment: If both trees grow at the same time you are probably having a Bad Smell called `Parallel inheritance hierarchies`

Comment: no i cannot do `super.bObject.method2()` in `A_Base1` because the object is of `class B` and not of `class B_Base1`

Comment: yeah.My bad. I didn't see your image properly.

Comment: @iberbeu I think you are right... I probably must re-design the things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using inheritance like this imo only makes sense if the Bx.methodX() do something that means she same to the different Ax. And in that case, you should name them that way:

```
public class B {
  public void doWhatAMeans() {
    method1();
  }

public class B1 extends B {
  @Override
  public void doWhatAMeans() {
    method2();
  }

public class B2 extends B {
  @Override
  public void doWhatAMeans() {
    method3();
  }
```

and then you only need A to call doWhatAMeans() and the A1 and A2 only need to be injected the appopriate instances of Bx.

On the other hand, if doWhatAMeans does not make sense because the methodX do different things that mean different things to Ax, then you need to rethink your object model, probably the parallel structures A,A1,A2 and B,B1,B2 are wrong then.

Comment: why does it not make any sense to have such definitions?? consider i have method `draw()` which draws objects according to different implementations.

Comment: In that case, you would have an interface or abstract class declaring draw() and have your implementations implement it. What you don't want is a Screen class and a Paper Class with their own draw(Object o) implementations that all start with if (o instanceof Circle) { drawCircle(o); } else if (o instanceof Square) { drawSquare(o); } and so on. In general, it's a smell whenever your caller hierarchy knows anything about your callee hierarchy and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

you could always cast. suppose your class A provides this method:

```
protected B getBInstance() {
   return bObject;
}
```

then in A_Base1 you could do something like:

```
((B_Base1)getBInstance()).method2();
```

this, however, is a VERY bad design. if your A_Base1 class needs an instance of B_Base1 it should be handed such an instance directly at construction time:

```
public class A_Base1 extends A {
   private B_Base1 b1Object;
   public A_Base1(B_Base1 instance) {
      super(B_Base1); //works as a B for parent
      this.b1Ovject = instance;
   }
}
```

and then you can use that

Comment: but `A_Base1` needs to call method in `B_Base1`, while `A_Base2` needs to call method in `B_Base2`

Comment: so A_Base2 will need to get an instance of B_Base2 in its constructor, in a smililar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

since A is a parent of A_Base1 (I'm assuming extended) you can make the function call that Accesses B public (or protected) and then A_Base1 or A_Base2 can use the same function A does to call into B.